# non-linear system

Tags: systems-of-equations, nonlinear-system, substitution

How to solve the following non-linear system?

$$
x^{2}=ax+by \\y^{2}=cx+dy
$$

I am guessing of a substitution here, as in solving one equation in $u$, where $u$ is some linear combination of $x$ and $y$, but the different coefficients make it hard to make a guess for $u$.

Comment: From the first, express $y$ as a function of $x$. Replace in the second and get a quartic in $x$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from your first equation we get
$$y=\frac{x^2-ax}{b}$$ for $b\ne 0$ plugging this in the second equation
$$\left(\frac{x^2-ax}{b}\right)^2=cx+\frac{d(x^2-ax)}{b}$$
can you simplify this?
and we get for $x$:
$$x \left( {a}^{2}x+dba-2\,a{x}^{2}-c{b}^{2}-dbx+{x}^{3} \right) =0$$

Comment: Could this be solved by $x^2 - (a+c)x + y^2 -(b + d)y = 0$ and then $x^2 - (a+c)x + ac + y^2 -(b + d)y +bd= ac+bd$?

Comment: i think no, you must eliminate one variable

Comment: It should work when $a=c$ and $b=d$, right?

Comment: but in this case you have two variables in one equation

Comment: Oh so that is what I was missing out. Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: i hope your Problem is solved now!

Comment: Yes it is. Appreciated.

Comment: thank you too kathi, have a nice evening!